# Product dimensions in Magento 2.2.5 update

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes, cart

I have installed **Magento 2.2.5** locally with sample data.

Now three new attributes **Length, Width, Height** Added. These are the default attributes, created by **Magento 2.2.5** or by some third party extensions.

And how to get these attribute values **Cart/Checkout**.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question "And how to get these attribute values Cart/Checkout". I just upgraded to 2.2.5 and noticed these new three attributes. The attribute code is `ts_dimensions_length` and `ts_dimensions_width`
`ts_dimensions_height`. I'm not sure why they added the suffix `ts`.

Comment: I suspect that one possible reason is to avoid conflicts with stores that had created their own custom attributes for length/width/height pre-2.2.5.

Comment: which modules or extensions for shipments have you installed?

Comment: @fasaro i am creating custom shipping module for my own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes `ts_dimensions_length` / `ts_dimensions_width` / `ts_dimensions_height` are part of the `Temando_Shipping` module that ships with Magento 2.

[ *Source:* Line 32 - 34 in `vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Setup/SetupData.php` ]

[image: Line 32 - 34 Temando_Shipping SetupData.php]

You should be able to get their values by using the code snippet below:

```
$product->getTsDimensionsLength();
$product->getTsDimensionsWidth();
$product->getTsDimensionsHeight();
```